# Why do my debugger randomly jump out of debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis-7.5

I'm experiencing a very annoying behaviour with the debugger in Visual Studio 2008 Professional. I'm debugging a ASP.NET web application, and when stepping through the code the debugger randomly "jumps out" of debug mode, but without the debugger stopping. So when I'm stepping through my code like this:

> step over, step over, step over, step
>   over,  ... , step over

The debugger continues as If I was pressing Continue, like this:

> step over, step over, step over, step
>   over,  ... , continue

Thing is, I never touch continue!

So, the debugger is still running, the ASP.NET page renders, but my "stepping" ends. This is of course very annoying. And it happens totally randomly.

Before switching to Windows 7 and IIS 7.5, I've never experienced this problem. My colleague who debugs the exact same code, but on a Windows XP machine running IIS 6 have never had this problem either. So my thought is, perhaps this is Windows 7 or IIS 7.5 related?

I've already made sure `<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" />` is set in web.config.

Have anyone experienced the same problem, or perhaps have an idea why I'm experiencing this annoying behavior?

Thanx!

P.S I realize this question might be more Visual Studio 2008 specific rather than programming specific, but I figure my best chance to find somebody that experienced the same problem would be at a forum for programmers (since naturally, programmers are the most frequent users of Visual Studio 2008).

Comment: I'm impressed that your colleague has got IIS 6 working on XP. To the best of my knowledge, only 5.1 works on there. (6 is for Server 2003)

Comment: It's very possible he's using 5.1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was due to a known problem with Visual Studio 2008 SP1. This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912) (with reffered hotfix) solved the problem.