# Visual Studio 2012 - Debugger Jumps around randomly

Tags: silverlight, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I've been having this issue for a while now an I just cant work past it anymore. I use to just recreate the project but now that solution no longer works for me either and i've had no luck with google at all.

I have a silverlight 5 website with a WCF service. Basically  what happens is I'll have a piece of code i need to debug e.g.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(AccessCardConnection))
            {
               connection.Open();
               var command = connection.CreateCommand();
               command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               command.CommandText = "GetAccessCardTimes";
               command.CommandTimeout = 300;
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", fullName);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstDate", firstDate);
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastDate", lastDate);
               var accessCardReader = command.ExecuteReader();

               while (accessCardReader.Read())
               {
                  var time = TimeSpan.Parse(accessCardReader["TotalOnSiteTime"].ToString());
                  duration += time;
               }
               return (duration.TotalHours);
            }
```

However once the first break point hits its anybodies guess which line it will jump to.. It doesnt follow any kind of logical order it, if i set a break point on connection.Open() for example it may jump back into the connection intialization then back down again and jump any which way it pleases, up, down, stay on the same line etc. Jumping in and out of methods as it seems to have no regard for what its doing.

None of the solutions I've found online have helped:

- [Why do my debugger randomly jump out of debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468177/why-do-my-debugger-randomly-jump-out-of-debug-mode) (Fix is for visual studio 2008)
- [Visual Studio 2010 Debugger jumps around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934073/visual-studio-2010-debugger-jumps-around) (Deleting the /bin and /obj files to regenerate the symbols didnt help)

Please can someone give me a hint as to what it may be I cant work like this :(

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Also i should note this only happens with silverlight/WCF projects, windows forms apps dont do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have multiple calls hitting the service. WCF spawns new worker threads for each request so what you are seeing is the debugger "jumping" from thread to thread.

Comment: I was indeed making a duplicate call to the service causing it to spawn a second identical worker. Thank you for your help!